# Pass value from HTML to Google Script on Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to pass a data value from the HTML to the Google Script on a GAS project. The parts with comments of the code is the value I need to pass.

**gs file**

```
function doGet(e) { 
      if (e.parameter.prefix){ 
        var result = data; // <-- GET VALUE "data" FROM THE HTML "forms.html"
        var content = e.parameters.prefix + '(' +JSON.stringify(result) + ')';
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(content)
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
        
      }
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
      return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    }
```

**Index.html in GAS project**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id='title' style="color: #e31414">SCRIPT</h1>
<h1 id='done' style="display: none"> DATA PASSED</h1>
<button id="btn" onclick="passData()">Run "passData()"</button>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function passData() {
   $('#done').show();
   var data = 'value'; //<-- PASS THIS DATA TO GOOGLE SCRIPT (The .gs file)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Follow these steps:**

1. in the gs file, create a variable without a value at the very top: `var data;`
2. Create a function below it like so:

```
function myfunction(x) {
    data = x;
}
```

3. in the Index.html file especially in `passData()` function, insert this line in the bottom of the function: `google.script.run.myfunction(data);`

Finally, you will be able to use the `result` variable as the data in `doGet()` function.

-- **your code should look like this** --

**gs file**

```
var data;

function myfunction(x) {
    data = x;
}

function doGet(e) { 
      if (e.parameter.prefix){ 
        var result = data; // <-- GET VALUE "data" FROM THE HTML "forms.html"
        var content = e.parameters.prefix + '(' +JSON.stringify(result) + ')';
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(content)
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
        
      }
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
      return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

**Index.html in GAS project**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id='title' style="color: #e31414">SCRIPT</h1>
<h1 id='done' style="display: none"> DATA PASSED</h1>
<button id="btn" onclick="passData()">Run "passData()"</button>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function passData() {
   $('#done').show();
   var data = 'value'; //<-- PASS THIS DATA TO GOOGLE SCRIPT (The .gs file)
   google.script.run.myfunction(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get an `undefined` response. This [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yesrpvqo/) show the problem in console. If the value on data is already  on the doGet(e) function (like "hi" or whatever) it works but with your way get that undefined. This is the [GAS Project](https://script.google.com/d/1OFR_AeVav9wBI9WRpjRB_X_34AiSiheGejzE-NPA63-aMCOZTZinBZVz/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I knew the problem!
the `doGet(e)` function executes (runs) only one time, when a user visits the web app. so when the user visits the web app the `doGet(e)`  function runs.
and after the page loads the user sends the data through `google.script.run`.
think about the `google.script.run` as an `ajax` call to the server,
and when that `ajax` runs, the  `myfunction(x)` runs and changes the data variable to the wanted value, but without executing the `doGet()`  function because as i said it only executes once when user visits the page. so the solution is to put the code in `myfunction(x)`

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I will check tall call to the server with `ajax`, because I have no idea how to implement it. Thank you very much @Faisal